# recovering scrambled ext4 partitions

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, data-recovery, ext4, testdisk

My year old 3TB Seagate drive stopped working. The drive had 3 ext4 1TB partitions which hold almost 2 years of accumulated data. I was using it in a ubuntu server when the mounted partitions stopped showing folders. On reboots, partitions would always mount but not show any data or show some folders with some data.

I took it out and attached it to a windows laptop via USB-to-SATA adapter. In AOEMI Partition Assistant Pro, the drive would show up but show weird partition scheme and sizes. Using the "Partition Recovery" option would also not work as it would be unable to find partitions:

[image]

I also tried using testdisk:

[image]
[image]
[image]

testdisk seems to locate 3 Linux partitions but its "Quick Analysis" feature returns the partition as FAT16 and something about "it can't be recovered because size is too small". This is my first time using these recovery tools so I have no idea what they mean. I did not do anything permanent for the fear of nuking all data. If anyone has an idea whats going on, please let me know.

Comment: [this review](http://dottech.org/95676/windows-best-free-partition-and-disk-manager-review/) doesn't seem to think AOMEI can handle ext4

Answer (score 0):

***NEVER USE WINDOWS TOOLS TO TRY TO RECOVER LINUX FILESYSTEMS!!!!!!!!!!***

Sorry for shouting, but you may have actually made matters worse by doing as you did. Windows doesn't understand Linux filesystems (although some tools can at least identify them, and in some cases you might be able to mount them by using appropriate drivers). Furthermore, using a USB adapter on an over-2TiB disk is also likely to cause problems. Many such devices will corrupt existing data on such a big disk. Some will be OK when the disk is used via the adapter from the start, but switching back and forth between the USB adapter and a direct SATA connection to the motherboard is likely to create new problems. The warnings in your screen shot to the effect that your disk seems smaller than it should are an indication that your USB adapter is incapable of handling your disk. If you wrote any data to the disk via that adapter, you've probably created new damage.

It's unclear if your original problem was caused by damage to the partition table or to your filesystems. Partition table damage can be fixed by proper use of `gdisk`, `parted`, or GParted; or in extreme cases by use of TestDisk. Filesystem damage can often be corrected by use of `fsck` or its filesystem-specific variants, such as `e2fsck`.

My recommendation at this point is to return the disk to its original computer and attempt recovery there. If you can't boot your original OS, use a *Linux* live CD. Use `gdisk` or `parted` to check the partition table and see if it's intact. I wrote [a Web page on repairing GPT disks with `gdisk`](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/repairing.html) that may be helpful to you. If your partition table looks OK, move on to filesystem repair.

You should seriously consider doing a low-level backup (using `dd`) to a disk of equal or greater size before you do anything else. Many repair procedures can actually make matters worse if they're applied inappropriately or if they go wrong. If you encounter such a problem, you'll be able to use a low-level backup for recovery.

Comment: The problem is, linux does not recognize the drive. Here's the dmesg output under ubuntu: http://pastebin.com/r3emUk3n

Comment: Also I have not written anything to the disk in windows.

Comment: If the drive is no longer being recognized in Linux, then that suggests a hardware failure. If you're lucky, it's a bad cable. If not, your motherboard (or at least its disk controller) may be damaged. You can use another computer, but be sure to use a SATA interface (or whatever the disk uses natively), ***NOT*** a USB adapter, to do the repairs. As I said, using Windows is also inadvisable. Using a USB drive and Windows in your case is like using a sledgehammer to fix your eyeglasses because you lacked a fine set of screwdrivers.

Comment: I get it sir, im a noob :)

Comment: OK. I inserted the disk back into the server and booted it up and wallah! everything came back. but the disk is slow. http://i58.tinypic.com/pb3r.jpg

Comment: The dmesg & syslog: http://pastebin.com/G9s1sJq0

Comment: You've got error codes on the disk, which suggests a physical fault of some kind. You might try [running a SMART test](http://askubuntu.com/questions/38566/how-can-i-check-the-health-of-my-hard-drive) on the disk. If that shows no problems, then it's likely a loose cable, a bad cable, or a failing disk controller on the motherboard, in order of ease of repair.

Comment: tried running `smartctl` but that threw an error. I guess this disk is gone. i bought this 2 yrs ago but it did run 24/7. i'm going to get something more fault tolerant in the future.